# Label Propagation Algorithm in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have a project in Python, here is how my data looks like : I have articles and the keywords of the articles.

I try to run Label Propagation with my data in Neo4j.

I have two types of nodes : "Articles" and "Keyword"
I have one relationship that link nodes keyword with nodes articles : "Appears_in"

Some articles has labels (string labels) and I don't know how to put this labels in seed labels.

I also don't know how to call LPA with two types of nodes.

Can you help me ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot put string labels as seed labels in the Label Propagation algorithm. You will have to create a mapping function that maps string labels to integer labels and then input those integer labels as seed.

For example if you have a graph like:

```
(:Node{label:'y'})-[:REL]->(:Node)<-[:REL]-(:Node{label:'x'})
```

Your mapping function would translate for example:

```
x -> 1
y -> 2
```

And then you can input those integer labels into Label propagation algorithm

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Is it possible to call LPA with multiple types of nodes ?

Comment: Yes it is possible... look at the docs: https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/management-ops/native-projection/

Comment: Thank you for your help Tomaž

Comment: The mapping function that maps string labels to integer labels has to be created in Neo4j ?